# Confusion regarding the notation used for in the Handbook of Applied Cryptography (integers subtracted from functions, cardinality of functions, etc)

Tags: random-variables, cryptography, law-of-large-numbers

I'm currently reading "[The Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)" (The full textbook is available as pdf documents from that page) and I'm struggling to understand some of the notation in Chapter 2 that's used on pages 51 and 52.

I've screenshotted the relevant sections:

---

[image: Calculating Variance]

---

[image: Law of large numbers]

---

My source of confusion comes from the (X-μ) in the first image. I don't really get it since X is meant to be a function and p is a number, I don't get how I can do integer subtraction (or maybe it's set difference) with that type mismatch? There must be something about the notation I'm not understanding.

My confusion with the second piece of notation is similar, how does one compute the cardinality of a function minus an number? Looking at this from a programmer's perspective there seems to be type violations here.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers subtracted from $X$ are to be understood as constant functions; subtraction is done pointwise.  So $(X-\mu)(z)=X(z)-\mu$, and similarly with $p$ in place of $\mu$.  The vertical lines in the second confusion mean absolute value (again computed pointwise), not cardinality.

Comment: In the latter example what would z be?

Comment: $z$ is a value in the domain of $X$. As I say in my answer, this is an "abuse of notation" which is nonetheless understood in context, as Andreas Bliss shows.

Comment: so, essentially "any value in domain X" or "all values in domain X" in this context?

Comment: In this context, any value in the domain.  But when taking expectations, for example, it's understood that you are summing over *all* the values in the domain, weighted by the probabilities.

Comment: @TomBusby I defined a random variable, i.e., a function on a probability space, namely $X-\mu$, by saying what its value is at each point $z$ in that space (the same space on which $X$ is a function).

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, it's assumed when dealing with expectations of random variables that you are acting on the *range* of the random variable, which is a set of numbers. So no type violation.  The second notation question is absolute value, not cardinality.

In general, math "abuses notation" a lot.  I imagine this is disconcerting from a programming perspective, but doing math is not the same as doing programming, and it is often clear from context what the abuse of notation is.  In your first example, it is understood that we are acting on the range of $X$, but it first needs to be explained that we are doing this.

Comment: I'm still confused about where we get this "range" from? And also, yes, I am aware of | | being used for absolute value too, but earlier in the chapter it defines it as cardinality, and never mentions that it will be used for absolute value. I would say, without outside knowledge coming from a more general familiar knowledge of mathematics, the notation is not obvious by context.

Comment: The *domain* of a function is the set of values you feed into the function, and the *range* is the set of values the function can output.  I agree, if you don't have some basic knowledge of probability, the page you show could be confusing.

Comment: So essentially, in the earlier example, we're dealing with:

Var(X) = E({(X1 - μ)^2, (X2 - μ)^2, ..., (Xn - μ)^2})

Comment: Your absolute value/cardinality confusion is a very good example of needing to know context.  If a number is in between the lines, it is understood to be absolute value, usually.  But if is a *set*, then it is understood to be cardinality, usually!

Comment: I'm still completely confused here

Comment: I don't get how I can be working on "one value" and "all values" at the same time

Comment: I think it's beginning to sink in, so the earlier example is saying:

The variance of a given value in X from the the mean of all the other possible values that X can produce is defined as 'that value' minus the mean of all the values in the domain of X.

Am i right?

Comment: It's the variance of a single value in the domain of X, rather than a measure of how spread apart the values in the domain of X actually are.

Comment: Look at Definition 2.12: it says to take an expectation, to sum across *all* the values of your random variables, weighted by the probabilities.  Think of the summation sign as a FOR/NEXT loop that loops over all the elements of the domain. You loop one element at a time, but you loop over all of them.  Does that help?

Comment: I understand the big sigma notation, i'm just not entirely understanding the purpose of the Var function itself i think

Comment: No, your variance explanation is exactly backwards. The variance is the dispersion of all the elements in the range versus the single mean (expected value), again weighted by probabilities.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that for all s in S, that X(s) will map to the same value? Because I looked up constant functions and that's what it describes them as

Comment: No, if all the $s$'s mapped to one value, $X$ wouldn't be a very interesting random variable.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, so I'm back to the same confusion where calling E(X), X *must* be a set of values rather than a single value... which you're saying it's not

Comment: No, I did not say that.  $X$ is a function, but we usually refer to it by the values in its range, which are a set of values.

Comment: So... given that, why was this wrong: "Var(X) = E({(X1 - μ)^2, (X2 - μ)^2, ..., (Xn - μ)^2})". You said I had confusion between sets and absolute values

Comment: Go back and look at 2.15, and see how it's defined in terms of 2.12. I'm sorry I'm not being much help, but I think you may need more work in basic probability theory, which would answer these questions.

Comment: To clarify, I'm saying that Xn is the output of X(Sn)

Comment: I thought I got 2.13 tbh, but you've told me conflicting things so far.

I understand 2.13 to be summation of (all the probabilities that X(Sn) produces a given x in R) * the value of that given x.

Comment: which should produce an average value which is the "most likely" value that X will produce, even if the *exact* value of E(X) isn't possible, kind of like the average of "2.1 children per family in the UK"

Comment: I just want to know why my expansion of X into being the range of values you were talking about is wrong, because if the variance is the measure of how spread out the possible values in the domain of X, and if we do use X in terms of its range... then I don't see how it's wrong.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, if this is an "abuse of notation" could you show me how it would be expressed in such a way as not to abuse notation, something a computer scientist would find satisfactory... because tbh, my image of mathematics as being the perfect world of formal description is being greatly tarnished here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the abuse of notation which is causing the confusion involves the notion of the preimage of an element of the codomain of the random variable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics) Consider fact 2.13 without the abuse of notation.

Let $ X $ be a random variable on $ S $. Then
\begin{equation}
 E(X) = \sum\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}}x \cdot P(X^{-1}(x)).
\end{equation}

In this definition I made the substitution $ P(X^{-1}(x)) $ for $ P(X = x) $. Since $ X $ is a function from the sample space to real numbers, and $ P $ is a function from subsets of the sample space to real numbers, we need to plug into $ P $ the set of elements in the domain of $ X $ which are mapped to a given real number value of $ x $. Thus $ X^{-1}(x) = \{ s \in S | X(s) = x \} $ and we now have the function $ P $ taking subsets of the sample space as required.

I believe the motivation for the abuse of notation is that it allows one to easily to both perform operations on the range of the random variable, while actually referring to the set of elements mapped to the output of the operations on the range.